# How to compute the probability distribution of $w=r_1\cdot a+r_2$ in $\mathbb{F}^*_p$

Tags: probability-distributions, finite-groups, finite-fields

Hypothesis: Let $\mathbb{F}^*_p$ be a finite field, where $p$ is a prime number. $r_1,r_2$ are elements of the field picked uniformly at random. Let $\alpha$ be a fixed element of the field.

**Question 1:** How to compute the distribution of $w=r_1\cdot \alpha+r_2$?

**Question 2:** How to compute the distribution of $w=r_1\cdot \alpha+r_2$, when $w\neq 0$?

---

Please feel free to answer one of the qustions.

Comment: For question 2, I'm not sure I understand the restriction to $w \neq 0$; $w$ is not chosen, it is determined by $r_{1}$, $r_{2}$, and $\alpha$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Can I ask you please what would your answer be for the first question. Thanks

Comment: You have several questions on the theme: what's the distribution of the $y=ax+b$ when we know the distribution of one or two of $a,x,b$ and the rest are fixed. Why do you keep asking these? The method is always the same and basically amounts to the fact that if you draw a line on the paper, there is no region of $y$-coordinates where that line would suddenly spend more time in. Unless its slope is zero, and it is a constant.

Comment: Furthermore, your account is not the only one asking similar questions. But the askers all come from a relatively small geographical area. There's something about the origin of these questions that you have not disclosed (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: $\mathbb{F}^*_p$ is not the field, but the multiplicative group of the field. (At least that's the normal notation.) Are the elements chosen from the field or the multiplicative group?

Comment: @otus They are chosen from $\mathbb{F}^*_p$. Cloud you also describe what happen if they are drawn from $\mathbb{F}_p$. Thank You.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you have been so helpful to me. So let's focus on the question and  leave the marginal discussion aside, please. As the only reason I'm here is to learn from you matematicians.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Also If you would like to know the whole story behind the question I'll be happy to discuss but it may take 10-15 minutes. Let me know please if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if $r_1, r_2$ are randomly chosen from $\mathbb{F}^*_p$, and $\alpha$ is a fixed element of $\mathbb{F}^*_p$.

**Question 1:**

$x = r_2 \cdot \alpha$ is a uniformly random element of the multiplicative group. $w$ is the sum of two independent uniformly random elements of the multiplicative group, which is not uniformly distributed.

The probability of $w = 0$ is $\frac{1}{p-1}$, while the probability of other field elements is $\frac{p-2}{(p-1)^2}$.

(The reason is that for any $x$ there is an $r_2$ such that $x+r_2 = 0$. However, for any $y \neq 0$ there is the possibility that $x=y$ which means $x + r_2 \neq y$ regardless of $r_2$.)

**Question 2:**

The answer depends on how $w \neq 0$ is "enforced", but if it is done with rejection sampling (generate new $r_1$, $r_2$ if $w = 0$), it is a uniformly random element of the multiplicative group. I.e. uniformly random out of the non-zero elements of the field.

---

Second, if $r_1, r_2$ are random elements of the $\mathbb{F}_p$ field.

**Question 1:**

Regardless of $\alpha$ and $r_1$, $r_1 \cdot \alpha$ is some element of the field that does not depend on $r_2$. Since $r_2$ is picked uniformly at random, $w$ is uniformly random as well.

**Question 2:**

The answer again depends on how $w \neq 0$ is "enforced", but with rejection sampling the answer is the same as above.

Comment: Yes, I can always use "rejection sampling". Because as a data owner, in the context of data security, who has a fixed element $\alpha$, I want my $w$ to be non-zero and then I can send it to an malicious server. But I did not know the term  "rejection sampling". And whether it affects the distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm wondering for the second case, question 2, when rejection sampling is used whether the element $w$ is distributed unifromly random in multiplicative group or in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @user153465, in the multiplicative group... It cannot be zero if you reject that.